# Axis of work vs. strand of work

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

Recently, I have been asking myself whether it is possible or not to use the word "axis/axes" to denominate one of the lines of actions -with a very clear and defined purpose- of a project. Similarly as the word "strand" is found sometimes. For example, if my project consists on children’s alphabetization, could I say one of my ‘axes of work’ is to find agreements with libraries for them to access without charge?

Answer (score 1):

"Axis of work" is not a commonly used phrase at all, nor is "strand of work,"  though it would be possible to define those phrases in context and use them.

More common phrases would be:

> One of the *aspects of the job/project/work* is to find agreements...
>   One of the *duties of the job* is...
>   One of the *facets of the job* is...
>   One of the *priorities of the job* is...

These have somewhat different meanings, but they are all focused on the various specific tasks that must be performed in order to complete the job.

Comment: *Subtask* might work.